# group by clause with where clause should return count zero also in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT * FROM A
1 A  ACCEPT
2 A ACCEPT
3 C ACCEPT
4 C ACCEPT
5 B HOLD
6 G HOLD
7 G HOLD
8 B REJECT
9 G REJECT
10 H REJECT
11 H REJECT
12 A NEW
13 H REJECT
14 H NEW
15 C NEW
16 D NEW
17 E NEW
18 D ACCEPT
19 D ACCEPT
20 F ACCEPT
21 I NULL
```

This is my table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PROD) FROM A
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
```

These are the products i have.

```
SELECT PROD,ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) FROM A WHERE STATUS='ACCEPT' GROUP BY PROD
A 2
C 2
D 2
F 1
```

When i execute this i am getting the above result

But my requirement :

```
A   2
B   0
C   2
D   2
E   0
F   0
G   0
H   0
I    1
```

How to achieve it.

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible with a simple query. None of your records that have `status=accept` contain a `B` or `E`, etc... You need to get a list of ALL of those letter codes, then join it against your table so you can have non-existing letters still get counted.

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly:

```
SELECT T.PROD,SUM(T.FLAG) AS [COUNT]
FROM
(
SELECT PROD, 1 AS FLAG
FROM A
WHERE STATUS='ACCEPT'
UNION ALL 
SELECT PROD, 0 AS FLAG
FROM A
WHERE STATUS <>'ACCEPT'
) AS T
GROUP BY T.PROD
ORDER BY T.PROD
```